# How to: Read the content of a selected DataGrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, string, binding, datagrid

**How to: Read the content of a selected DataGrid row**

I have got a `DataGrid` which is filled by a class (MyClass) through `Binding`. That works perfect. Now, I would like to get the content of a field from the selected row.

Example: Doe John CEO 2002
Now, when I select this row, I would like to save the (first) content "Doe" into a string.

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGrid_Test.SelectedItems[0];
string s = row["LastName"].ToString();
```

But doing it that way, I just get an error message:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled.
Unable to cast object of type "MyClass" to type "System.Data.DataRowView".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedItem` property is bound to your `MyClass` object. Retrieve the property this way:

```
MyClass obj = (MyClass)dataGrid_Test.SelectedItems[0];
string s = myClass.LastName;
```

Comment: Well done! Thanks a lot, you/this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can select the selected row of a datagrid by using the code:

```
String info = dataGrid_Test.CurrentRow.Cells["someColumnName"].ToString();
```

you can replace the string to be whatever you need and use loops to grab more info from the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I like to take the datatable away from the datagridview and manipulate that. But I think your main problem here is that you're not accessing the "value" property.

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGrid_Test.SelectedItems[0];
string s = row["LastName"].Value.ToString();
```

But, as far as using datatables, you can grab the datasource and get a datarow. Here it is in vb.net:

```
   Dim DT as Datatable = Datagridview.datasource 
   Dim datarow As DataRow = DT.Rows(0)
   Dim strItem As String = datarow.Item("ColumnName")
```

Answer (score 0):

CurrentItem worked as  well (got the answer thanks to DotN3TDev's clue)

Basically, SelectedItem seemed to be an inconsistent because I set a breakpoint and debugged, and sometimes got a successful cast to DataRowView and the cast exception occurred only some times! So another approach would be:

```
var row = (DataRowView) dataGrid_Test.CurrentItem;
var s = row["LastName"].ToString();
```

Update: It still was inconsistent, because it was actually a new row that was selected. So one way is to

- check if the value of dataGrid_Test.SelectedIndex exceeds the current row count.
- Alternatively, use *is* to ensure its an existing row, else assume its a new row

  ```
  if (dataGrid_Test.CurrentItem is DataRowView)
  {
      var row = (DataRowView) dataGrid_Test.CurrentItem;
      var s = row["LastName"].ToString();

      // do stuff - selected existing row
  }
  else
  {
      // selected the new (last) row
      // do other stuff - 
  }
  ```

If you want to disable this behaviour, you can set a flag on the DataGrid:

```
CanUserAddRows="False"
```

Or in case you don't want anything to be neither added nor even editable, but only selectable....

```
IsReadOnly="True"
```